# Require JSON file with DOJO

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I'm using `define/declare` from the Dojo API to load modules, but I also want to load a *.json* config file, but it is ignoring the extension and trying to load a *.js* file

```
define([
        "./Config.json",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ],
    function(
        config
    ){ 
    var config = JSON.parse(config);
    console.log(config);
})
```

Through the console I can see it is trying to load "`Config.json.js`" instead of "`Config.json`", how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [dojo/text](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/text.html) plugin could help you

try to load the file as bellow ( be sur of the path to your file )

```
define([
    "dojo/text!./Config.json",
    "dojo/domReady!"
],
function(config){ 
    var config = JSON.parse(config);
    console.log(config);
})
```